# Java : type is not applicable for the arguments (K)

Tags: java

i'm getting

> The method makeSet(Comparable) in the type UnionFindSet is not
> applicable for the arguments (K)

And don't know how to solve it , i tried to implement comparable but nothing changes...

My class Node

```
public class Node <T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>>
```

My class UnionFindSet uses Node :

```
public class UnionFindSet <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Method makeSet :

```
 public void makeSet(T data){
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
    node.data(data)
    .rank(0)
    .parent(node);
    node_map.put(data, node);
 }
```

---

My class where i get the error :

```
public class Graph<K ,E>
```

---

and in method :

```
public void mstKruskal() {
    List<Edge<K, E>> secure_edges = new LinkedList<>();
    UnionFindSet partition = new UnionFindSet<>();
    List<Edge<K, E>> my_edges = new LinkedList<>();

    my_edges = this.getEdges();

    Collections.sort(my_edges, new Comparator<Edge<K, E>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Edge<K, E> left, Edge<K, E> right) {
            return (int) (left.getWeight() - right.getWeight());
        }
    });

    for (Map.Entry<K, List<Edge<K, E>>> entry : this.G.entrySet()) {
        partition.makeSet(entry.getKey()); //-------------------> here i get the error 
        
    }


    System.out.println(my_edges.toString());
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a raw type, `    UnionFindSet partition = new UnionFindSet<>();` Doesn't UnionFindSet require a parameter?

Comment: @matt true , didn't noticed that

Comment: @matt it's in the first line : The method makeSet(Comparable) in the type UnionFindSet is not applicable for the arguments (K)

Comment: Doing : UnionFindSet<K> = new UnionFindSet<K>(); I'm getting : Bound mismatch: The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type UnionFindSet<T> , i dont think that k is comparable

Comment: do you mean  public class Graph<K , E extends Comparable<K>>  ?  with this still getting the error

Comment: @matt how should i declare my graph?

Comment: A [mcve] would really help here...

Comment: @Singh You shoud adhere to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase, so no underscores. Further, is there a reason why you are using an anonymous subclass of `Comparator` instead of a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to have happened, you've created a class and then created a "raw type version".

```
UnionFindSet partition = new UnionFindSet<>();
```

Then when you try to use it's method,

```
public void makeSet(T data)
```

It gives you an error. Since you want to use "makeSet(key)" on your `K` type. To fix this you need to parameterize UnionFindSet,

```
UnionFindSet<K> partition = new UnionFindSet<>();
```

This has an error because you didn't declare `K` as Comparable, so you can update your graph declaration.

```
class Graph<K extends Comparable<K>, E>
```

That way you can use the K as a parameter of the UnionFindSet.